# Resizing Images With Aspect Ratio using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm trying to resize some images using VBScript:

```
Resize Image NewWidth=200
```

Just something like the code above, it will resize the image with the newwidth and will keep aspect ration for height.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: VBScript has no inherit functionality to work with images. You'll need to use a third-party COM library that is accessible by VBScript (i.e., it must support late binding via IDispatch). See [this page](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_asp-resize-image/) for an example.

Comment: Have a look at this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_image_viewers), look for batch and resize feature